# ember firebase pass models to action handler

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I have ember data models hooked with firebase, characters and spells. I can create new models and save them to firebase. Now I wanted to add spells to character. I defined that character has many spells:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  chClass: DS.attr(),
  chName: DS.attr(),
  chImage: DS.attr(), 
  chSpells: DS.hasMany('spell', {async: true}),
});
```

In my hbs I listed spells in `<select>` element, there is also input fields and add button.

```
Add new character <br>
name {{input value=mchName }}<br>
class {{input value=mchClass }}<br>
image {{input value=mchImage }}<br>

<br>
Choose Spells:<br>
<select name="spellslist" multiple>
{{#each spells as |spell index|}}
 <option value="{{index}}">{{spell.spName}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>

<button {{action 'addChar' spells}}>add</button><br>
```

So when user types in character name, level and picks some spells I want to call addChar action function on add button and pass this data.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
mchName:'',
mchClass:'',
mchImage:'',
store: Ember.inject.service(),

actions: {
addChar: function(spells) {
  var newChar = this.store.createRecord('character');
  newChar.set("chName", this.mchName);
  newChar.set("chClass", this.mchClass);
  newChar.set("chImage", this.mchImage);
  newChar.get("chSpells").addObject(?????? how to get spell here ?????);

  newChar.save();
```

I know how to pass string from inputs, but I dont know how to pass selected spells to this function, its killing me.

Comment: have you seen Ember Power Select - http://www.ember-power-select.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you (as admin) are going to populate the spells table. Now ... assuming that a character can have many spells and a spell can have many characters, here's how one can approach this (note that I'm using a controller ... you should ideally be doing this in a component):

Character model is simplified:

```
//app/models/character.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  chName: DS.attr(),
  chSpells: DS.hasMany('spell', {async: true})
});
```

Spells model is also simplified for this example:

```
//app/models/spell.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  spName: DS.attr(),
  spellChar: DS.hasMany('character', {async: true})
});
```

We need an include helper for the multiline select. Review [this article](http://balinterdi.com/2015/09/25/select-in-ember-with-multiple-selection.html) for details:

```
//app/helpers/include.js
 import Ember from 'ember';
  export function include(params/*, hash*/) {
  const [items, value] = params;
  return items.indexOf(value) > -1;
   } 
  export default Ember.Helper.helper(include);
```

Here's the application route:

```
app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    var spells = this.store.findAll('spell');
    return spells;
  }
});
```

And the application controller:

```
//app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedSpellIds: [],
  actions: {
    selectSpell(event){
      const selectedSpellIds = Ember.$(event.target).val();
      this.set('selectedSpellIds', selectedSpellIds || []);
    },
    addChar: function(){
      var charName = this.get('mchName');
      var _this = this;
      var spells = this.get('selectedSpellIds');
      var spellObjArray = spells.map(function(spellId){
        return _this.store.peekRecord('spell', spellId );
      });
      var charToSave = this.store.createRecord('character', {
          chName: charName,
          chSpells: spellObjArray
      });
      charToSave.save();
    },
  }
});
```

And the application template:

```
//app/templates/application.hbs
Add new character <br>
name {{input value=mchName }}<br>

<br>
Choose Spells:<br>
<select multiple onchange={{action "selectSpell"}}>
{{#each model as |spell|}}
 <option value={{spell.id}} selected={{include selectedSpellIds spell.id}}>{{spell.spName}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>

<button {{action 'addChar'}}>add</button><br>
```

Comment: Thank  you for reply, but my problem is how to get spell object, that i can put to this line: newChar.get("chSpells").addObject(?????? how to get spell here ?????);

Comment: okay ... so it looks like the character returns a promise to you and you need to use a "then" in order to resolve the promise. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: newChar.get("chSpells") returns empty array that I am yet to populate with my spell. That is why I call addObject(*spell*) after that. So what I need is *spell* object.

Comment: okay. I've redone my answer. Hope this helps you. Let me know if you need me to put up the code on github.